# Day of the week using Zeller's Congruence - Python 3

Tags: python

I just started studying Computer Science and I'm very new to python 3 and coding in general. Our first assignment is to calculate the day of the week using Zellers Congruence, and I have a few questions regarding the code that I have written.

```
year = int(input("Year: "))
while not int(year) in range(1583, 10000):
    year = input("Out of allowed range 1583 - 9999. Please enter a valid 
number: ")

month = int(input("Month: "))
while not int(month) in range(1, 13):
 month = input("Out of allowed range 1 - 12. Please enter a valid number: ")

if month == 1 or month == 2:
 month += 12
 year -= 1 

day = int(input("Day: "))
while not int(day) in range(1, 32):
        day = input("Out of allowed range 1 - 31. Please enter a valid 
number: ")


result = ( day + 13 * (month+1) // 5 + year + year // 4
 - year// 100 + year // 400 ) % 7


weekday = {0: "Saturday",1: "Sunday", 2: "Monday",3: "Tuesday",4: 
"Wednesday",5: "Thursday",6: "Friday"}

print("The day is " + weekday[int(result)] + ".")
```

First off, I'm supposed to make sure that the day range is related to the correct months. For example when the month input is 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10 or 12, the day interval should be 1 - 31. If the month input is 4, 6, 9, or 11 the day interval should be 1-30. And lastly I have to take leap years into account aswell. And I cant figure out how to write these requirements.

Also, all critique is welcome. I know that this is far from decent, so please let me know what I could do better!

Comment: For " I'm supposed to make sure that the day range is related to the correct months." you could do if month in [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]: valid_days = range(1, 32) elif month in [4, 6, 9, 11]: valid_days = range(1, 31)

Comment: I would say just go through this: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python  what you are looking to do could probably simply be hard coded

Comment: To determine if it's a leap year you need to check if the year is divisible by 4 and if it's divisible by 400 but not by 100. You could do it in a one-liner like this: is_leap =year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)

Comment: Errata: full algo off wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm

Comment: @BoboDarph Thank you for your help. Could you show me where these lines of code should be added? And also how to make the input string change if the input is out of range?

Comment: I don't understand the second question and doing the first would be solving your assignment for you.

Comment: @BoboDarph Okay Bobo, fair enough! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think I understand your second question now. You want to sanitize your input for year/month/day, right?

Comment: When the user inputs something out of range like "Month: 13", they are prompted with "Out of allowed range 1 - 12. Please enter a valid number: ".

I want to add variations of that to the "day" section dependig on the input. For example: ("Out of allowed range 1 - 31. Please enter a valid number: "), ("Out of allowed range 1 - 30. Please enter a valid number: ") and ("Out of allowed range 1 - 29. Please enter a valid number: ")

Comment: year = 0
while not int(year) in range(1583, 10000):
    year = int(input('Reading Year. Valid values are 1583 to 10000 : Please enter the year. ')) Please mind the tabbing (very important in python) when using in your homework. Also note that this won't save you if the value they enter is not an integer

Comment: I might be punching over my weight right now. Maybe it's smarter to get a greater understanding of the language before trying to code with tools that i dont fully understand... ill be back later when i feel like i posses the knowledge to continue with this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Zeller's congruence handles the leap years correctly. If your problem is making sure the input date is a valid one, I believe the simplest approach will be creating a python `datetime.date` object using the user input.

```
import datetime
... # get user inputs
date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
```

If there is any invalid input, python will raise a meaningful exception. You don't need to do any validation yourself, just reading them as integers will be enough.